# Suggestions on laying out web pages using CSS

Tags: css

This is the text:

> productName $100 Add to Cart

I want to layout the text in follow:

> ```
> productName 
> $100              Add to Cart
> ```

the "productName", and "$100" should align left, and Add to Cart should align right, 
I know that it can be done using table tag, but apart from tables, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following markup will work.  You might want to limit the width of either of the divs of course, as they will be 100% of their parent container widths.

```
<div>
  productName
  <div>
    <span style="float:right">Add to Cart</span>
    $100
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @zombat it would be nice to see a variation on this with an `a` tag (since it implies an action) and external CSS vs. Inline. Either way, +1

Comment: True, I suppose the "Add to Cart" definitely implies a link.  `<a style="float:right">Add to Cart</a>` would work just as well.  Also, while I fully agree that CSS should be external wherever possible, I usually end up putting it inline for Stack Overflow answers to increase clarity.

Comment: I figured with 17.4K rep, you did it on purpose :) Makes total sense. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="name">Product Name</div>
    <div class="clear">
        <div class="price">
            $100
        </div>   
        <div class="actions">
            <a href="#">Add</a> to <a href="#">Cart</a> 
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .product{ //if you care to specify a width }
  .product .name{ padding: 5px 0; } 
  .product .price, .product .actions{ float: left; padding: 5px 0; }   
  .product .price{ width: 150px;} //customize width to your preference
  .product .actions{ width: 350px; } //customize width to your preference
  .product .actions a{ margin: 0 5px;} 

  .clear{ overflow: hidden;} //reusable class for clearing floats
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "Float" tags in your divs

Answer (score 0):

Try placing each of the 3 in separate divs and then float them left or right inside a containing which has a fixed width.